# Selenium Bot: Irregular Switching of Windows

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, timeoutexception

Once I'm clicking the element ***More Information***, the link is getting clicked and then the window is jumping back to it's previous window and a ***TimeoutException*** is being shown.

Code:

```
self.driver.window_handles
        base = "https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox/id/AAQkADQ0ZmY1YmRkLWExNDEtNGNlYS1iOTZmLTVmNzNjMzhkNjUyMgAQAJmE%2FyrhD0supMphUUSGrmQ%3D"
        window_set = {self.driver.window_handles[0], self.driver.window_handles[1]}

        for x in window_set:
            if(base != x):
                self.driver.maximize_window()
                wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
                self.driver.switch_to.window(x)
                frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "mainFrame")))
                self.driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
                element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mc-lnk-moreInfo")))
                element.click()
```

Please ***HELP***!

WebPage Image:***(contains both the tabs)***

In this image ***More Information*** has been clicked and has changed to ***Less Information***

[image: Web Page Image]

Comment: Why are you using list of window_set ( iterating through for loop )? And once you click on more information link what is expected behaviour ?

Comment: I want to stay in the second window even after clicking the link

Comment: what action you want to perform after clicking on a more information link ?

Comment: driver.get("url") is changing the url in my previous window and the link is opening there but the focused window still remains on the second window

Comment: As I mentioned previosuly, what action you want to perform after clicking on a more information link ? would be great if you let me know because its easy for me to provide you solution as of now you are just telling me foccus should be on secoonf window

Comment: after clicking the on more information the link should expand and the code should end theere

Comment: after clicking on the link the program should just stop there

Comment: you mean say meeting number or soomething else ?

Comment: I didn't get you. The window that is shown here was opened from another link in another tab. Whenever I run your solution, that previous window's link gets altered with the current window and the link is clicked there. But I dont want that. I just want the more information link to get clicked and the code should just end there

Comment: Obviously that is going to happen because have not provided me code for a another link which will open your current page . what ever you asked me i have provided solution based on that: If you want you can amend your code and providde entire code there or else you can describe your problem properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job!

```
self.driver.window_handles
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        base = self.driver.window_handles[0]
        child = self.driver.window_handles[1]
        windows = {self.driver.window_handles[0], self.driver.window_handles[1]}

        for x in windows:
            if(base != x):
                self.driver.switch_to.window(x)
                frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "mainFrame")))
                self.driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
                element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mc-lnk-moreInfo")))
                element.click()
```